# Can't open camera by index OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have a chromebook, and am using VSCode as my IDE with Python3 as my language. When running this code I get the error:

> [ERROR:0@0.014] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:156 getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

I've changed the index to different values, nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

**Camera index Out of range, it means your device camera is not detecting.**

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

-Ensure that you have a camera connected or built-in to your Chromebook and that it is functioning properly.

-Check the camera index being used is correct. The index should correspond to the camera device you want to access. Keep in mind that camera indexes typically start from 0, so the first camera would have an index of 0, the second camera an index of 1, and so on.

Comment: Here's the thing, the camera works and I have checked the range. There is only one camera on my computer.